# Where can I find a Perl module for converting a Perl data structure into a JavaScript one?

Tags: javascript, perl, json, data-structures, mason

Where can I find a Perl module for converting a Perl data structure into a JavaScript one?

e.g. this is my code (Mason):

```
% # convert our @cti data structure into a javascript one
  var cti = [
% foreach my $cti_category (@cti) {
             {
                 label: "<% $cti_category->{'label'} %>",
                 value: "<% $cti_category->{'value'} %>",
                 children: [
%     foreach my $cti_type (@{$cti_category->{'children'}}) {
                            {
                              label: "<% $cti_type->{'label'} %>",
                              value: "<% $cti_type->{'value'} %>",
                            },
%     }
                           ]
             },
% }
            ];
```

is there a module for this?

Comment: Now that everybody's said JSON, how about adding the json tag to your question? :D

Answer (score 16):

JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation, which is the format you're looking for.

Unfortunately, none of the modules you're looking for are in the Perl core, but they are available on CPAN, as a quick [search](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=JSON&mode=all) will reveal.

I'd actually recommend installing [JSON::Any](http://search.cpan.org/author/RBERJON/JSON-Any-1.17/lib/JSON/Any.pm) as a wrapper, as well as [JSON::XS](http://search.cpan.org/author/MLEHMANN/JSON-XS-2.2222/XS.pm) (if you have a C compiler) or one of [JSON](http://search.cpan.org/author/MAKAMAKA/JSON-2.12/lib/JSON.pm) and [JSON::Syck](http://search.cpan.org/~audreyt/YAML-Syck-1.05/lib/JSON/Syck.pm) if you don't. JSON::Any provides an [interface class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_pattern) on top of several other JSON modules (you can choose, or let it pick from what's installed) that's independent of which module you wind up using. That way, if your code should need to be ported elsewhere, and (say) the target machine can install JSON::XS when you can't, you get a performance boost without any extra code.

```
use JSON::Any;

my $j = JSON::Any->new;

$json = $j->objToJson($perl_data);
```

Like so.

Answer (score 8):

Check out [JSON](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON) or [JSON::XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON::XS).

To elaborate a bit more, JSON is "JavaScript Object Notation", and the two modules above convert perl data structures into that format.

Answer (score 0):

[JSON](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.53/lib/JSON.pm) !

> This module converts Perl data structures to JSON and vice versa using either JSON::XS or JSON::PP.

Answer (score 0):

The [JSON](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.12/lib/JSON.pm) module will convert data structures - it's basically a to/from JSON serializer.